# How can I return XML from boto calls?

Tags: python, xml, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-mws

I am using [boto 2.32.1](https://github.com/boto/boto) with Python 2.7.6. I am having problems with the [list_orders](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/mws.html#boto.mws.connection.MWSConnection.list_orders) function of boto's mws modules to get the XML data of my Amazon orders.

Here is the call I make:

```
response = connection.list_orders(CreatedAfter='2014-08-26T05:53:44+00:00', 
   MarketplaceId=['XXXXXXXXXXXXX'])
```

Here is the value of `response` (with personal information removed obviously)

```
ListOrdersResponse{u'xmlns': u'https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01'}
(ListOrdersResult: ListOrdersResult{}
(CreatedBefore: u'2014-08-26T10:06:10Z', Orders: ^Orders^{}
(Order: [Order{}(***ORDER INFORMATION***)])), 
ResponseMetadata: ^ResponseMetadata^{}(RequestId: u'xxxxxxxxxx'))
```

This isn't ideal because I have another module for eBay sales that works with the XML returned by ebaysdk-python. Amazon formats their XML similarly to eBay so if I could get the XML returned by Amazon instead of the format above, it would be brilliant.

I have noticed that if I use `boto.set_stream_logger('boto')`, it will print the XML returned so maybe I could take advantage of that somehow?

This is what I would like to be returned:

```
<ListOrdersResponse xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01">
  <ListOrdersResult>
    <Orders>
      <Order>
        ***ORDER INFORMATION***
      </Order>
    </Orders>
    <CreatedBefore>2014-08-26T10:18:59Z</CreatedBefore>
  </ListOrdersResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</ListOrdersResponse>
```

I could then use Python's xml.etree.ElementTree to parse and work with the data.

Comment: Hi I too want to get orders from mws. but keep running into errors. If it is okay with you can you share your code? It can help me on the problem.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's an officially supported method to do this, but you can do this to get the raw XML response back easily:

```
# Set up
from boto.mws.connection import MWSConnection
MWSConnection._parse_response = lambda s, x, y, z: z

# Usage
result = az.get_matching_product_for_id(MarketplaceId="ATVPDKIKX0DER",
                                            SearchIndex="Books",
                                            IdType="ASIN",
                                            IdList=[0439023521])
# <?xml version="1.0"?>\n<GetMatchingProductForIdResponse xmlns...
```